# .click javascript function in android WebView

Tags: java, javascript, android, click, android-webview

I'm trying to click on a link in a page through a WebView programmatically.

My Java function.

```
public class Refresh extends Activity{

WebView planView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_refresh);

    planView=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webViewRefresh);
    planView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    planView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavaScriptInterface(this), "Call");
    planView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    planView.setWebViewClient(new InsideWebViewClient());
    planView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
    planView.loadUrl(link);
    planView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override  
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)  
        {   
            planView.loadUrl("javascript:window.document.getElementsByTagName('a')[6].click()"); //This little thing isn't working
        }
});}
```

But there is a problem with this click() function.

Here is the error

> TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating "window.document.getElementsByTagName('a')[6].click()") at undefined:1

I'm really new to Java, Android and Javascript.

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

maybe it will work if you remove the `window.` part of the Javascript code.